# Hexadecimal representation of a negative signed 8-bit integer

Tags: c, hex, printf

In a portion of my program, I'll have to manage signed 8-bit integers. I have no problem to display them as decimals using `printf` and `%d` formatting.

However, when it comes to hexadecimal representation, the formatting of a negative `int8_t` variable is not shown as a 8-bit hexadecimal (`0xXX`) but as a **32-bit** hexadecimal (`0xFFFFFFXX`).

Here is the snippet of code, describing my problem:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main()
{
    int8_t value = 0;
    
    printf("t = %d = 0x%02X\n", value, value);
    t = 127;
    printf("t = %d = 0x%02X\n", value, value);
    t = -128;
    printf("t = %d = 0x%02X\n", value, value);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Compilation and execution give:

```
t = 0 = 0x00
t = 127 = 0x7F
t = -128 = 0xFFFFFF80
```

I would like to get `0x80` and not `0xFFFFFF80`. What did I do wrong? How to display the negative signed 8-bit integer as a 8-bit hexadecimal?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problematic 'sign extension' is happening because, for your `%X` format specifier, the expected argument type is of *int* size, so your `int_8` argument, after being suitably promoted (and sign-extended), is then printed as a 'full-size' *unsigned* integer.

You can prevent the latter part by adding the `hh` length modifier to the format, which indicates that the corresponding argument is of `char` size, so only the least-significant byte will be printed:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main()
{
    int8_t value = 0;

    printf("t = %d = 0x%02hhX\n", value, value);
    value = 127;
    printf("t = %d = 0x%02hhX\n", value, value);
    value = -128;
    printf("t = %d = 0x%02hhX\n", value, value);

    return 0;
}
```

[Further Reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf)

---

Note: As pointed out in the comments here, and in other answers, the use of the `%X` format specifier (with or without a length modifier) for an argument of **signed** type is, formally, undefined behaviour (though it will likely work on the vast majority of modern systems).

To avoid such potential UB, a better way to achieve your goal is to *explicitly* cast your `int8_t` argument(s) to the unsigned equivalent (of the same bit size – or `uint8_t`, in your case). Then, when the "default argument promotion" is applied, it will be performed ***without sign extension*** (as all possible values of a `uint8_t` are representable in an `int`); thus, there will then be no need to add the `hh` length modifier to your format, as the upper (added) bits of the resultant `unsigned int` values will not be set.

This code gives your desired result in a well-defined way:

```c
int main()
{
    int8_t value = 0;
    printf("t = %d = 0x%02X\n", value, (uint8_t)value);
    value = 127;
    printf("t = %d = 0x%02X\n", value, (uint8_t)value);
    value = -128;
    printf("t = %d = 0x%02X\n", value, (uint8_t)value);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: %x actually expects unsigned int but that's not why. Integer promotion happens as part of "the default argument promotions", regardless of what conversion specifier you gave printf.

Comment: @Lundin Correct on the *unsigned* part, which is why I said "... of *int* **size** ..."

Comment: `%hhx` is not correct format for `uint8_t` . `PRIx8` is.

Comment: The first paragraph is not correct. The promotion of arguments is not affected by the format string. (The format may not even be known by the compiler at this point) . Instead the *default argument promotions* are applied to each argument, regardless of the format string

Comment: @M.M Yes - you are correct that my answer is (partially) incorrect. I shall edit the first part, but I am looking for a way that doesn't (overtly) copy stuff from your answer.

Comment: "for your %X format specifier, the expected argument type is of int size" --> C specifies that `"%X"` needs to match an `unsigned`, not a "type is of int size".  OP's code and this are UB - a nice UB.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Well, as we don't like UB on Stack Overflow, I added an 'appendix'. Hope you approve! :-)

Answer (score 3):

When integer types smaller than `int` are passed to a variadic function like `printf` they are *promoted* to type `int`.  So a `int8_t` with value -1 and representation 0xff becomes an `int` with value -1 and representation 0xffffffff.

That's why you're seeing the values you are while using `%x` which expects and prints an `int`.  To indicate that you're printing a `char` value, use `%hhx` which will convert the value to `char` before printing.

```
printf("t = %d = 0x%02hhX\n", value, value);
```

Alternately, you can cast the value to `uint8_t` to better match what `%x` expects:

```
printf("t = %d = 0x%02X\n", value, (uint8_t)value);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I did not know that there was a type "transformation" when using printf function. I thought about it and tried casting (int8_t) but it was overwritted. You solution works very well, as I wanted.

Comment: If you feel the edit (added "Note:...") to my question is too much a copy of the last part of yours, just let me know, and I'll try to do something about it. But I hadn't read your answer (fully) when I made the edit to my own.

Answer (score 3):

This code has [undefined behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/). The behaviour of the `%X` format specifier is only defined by the language standard for the case of an argument of type `unsigned int`.  You provided an `int8_t` instead.

In practice you may (but this is not guaranteed) find that the `printf` function tries to read an `unsigned int` from the location where integer arguments are stored, and what you are seeing corresponds to how that location gets filled up by an `int8_t` value.

Answer (score 1):

This is because of default promotion of integer arguments. You need to use correct format specifiers and cast:

```
int main(void)
{
    int8_t value = 0;
    
    printf("t = %d = %02" PRIx8 "\n", value, value);
    value = 127;
    printf("t = %d = 0x%02" PRIx8 "\n", value,(uint8_t)value);
    value = -128;
    printf("t = %d = 0x%02" PRIx8 "\n", value, (uint8_t)value);
    
    return 0;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/jMqhz5156

Comment: There is no conversion of arguments corresponding to the ellipsis.  There are the *default argument promotions* which may or may not result in a signed integer. For example an `unsigned int` argument is not promoted.

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to get 0x80 and not 0xFFFFFF80.

`0x80` represents the value +128<sub>10</sub>.

To print -128 as `0x80` without *undefined behavior*, do not attempt to print negative numbers with `"%X"`.  Convert to a positive number first.

```
t = -128;
// printf("t = %d = 0x%02X\n", value, value); 
printf("t = %d = 0x%02X\n", value, (uint8_t) value);
```

`(uint8_t) value` converts `int8_t` negative values by adding 256.  Passing the `uint8_t` to a ... argument converts to an `int` with values in the range [0...255].

`"%X"` expects an `unsigned`.  Passing an `int` to a `...` argument that is read as an `unsigned` is OK as long as the value is representable in both (e.g. positive) per C17dr §6.5.2.2 6.

Pedantically, to not rely on §6.5.2.2 6:

```
printf("t = %d = 0x%02X\n", value, (unsigned) (uint8_t) value);
```